# Get mode of windows services using java

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

My task is to get the details of particular services running in windows using java. I am able to get service status but I found nothing which shows the mode(automatic, manual) using java.

How do I get the mode of a service?

This is the code I am using to get the status of windows service-

```
String status = "";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc \\\\" + host + " query \"" + serviceName + "\"");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (line.trim().startsWith("STATE")) {
        boolean state = line.contains("RUNNING");
        if (state)
            status = "Running";
        else
            status = "Stopped";
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty to execute this command:

`sc qc <service_name>`

```
sc qc prgnDiscAgent
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: prgnDiscAgent
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\Discovery Agent\bin32\discagnt.exe"
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : HP DDMI Agent
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```